# multiple plots with different bin range

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

would like to plot some histograms, for that I used the following lines:

```
lst  =  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
X_dum=pd.get_dummies(df[lst].copy())
mask = np.triu(X_dum.corr())
_ = X_dum.hist(figsize=(12,12))
plt.savefig('figures/hist_2.png')
```

which will create the requested histograms, but since there are outliers I would like to set the bins manually.
If I do it, plot by plot it works. But if I use the same approach as before

```
plot_bins = [range(1,6),range(0,5),range(0,4_000_000,500_000),range(0,2100,300)]
lst  =  ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
X_dum=pd.get_dummies(df[lst].copy())
mask = np.triu(X_dum.corr())
_ = X_dum.hist(bin=plot_bins, figsize=(12,12))
plt.savefig('figures/hist_3.png')
```

I receive the  following error message:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'range' and 'range'

Is there just an error in my code or do I need to plot every plot separately?

Comment: when I reduce the entries for plot_bins and lst to two I receive the following: "ValueError: `bins` must be 1d, when an array". Same when I replace the range() by lists in the plot_bin list

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `plot_bins` is a list of several `range` objects. You need to flatten it out to have a single list (1-d) containing your bin values. So you can try the following

```
plot_bins = [range(1,6),range(0,5),range(0,4_000_000,500_000),range(0,2100,300)]

plot_bins = sorted([i for sublist in plot_bins for i in sublist])

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 500000, 1000000, 1500000, 2000000, 
#  2500000, 3000000, 3500000, 0, 300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500, 1800]

# Rest of the code

_ = X_dum.hist(bin=plot_bins, figsize=(12,12))
```

Comment: if  I plot just one plot it works with range(), your solution seem to not work. Error message: "ValueError: `bins` must increase monotonically, when an array"

Comment: @ChrisFoobar : I edited my answer. I now use `sorted` after flattening the list

Comment: Yes  and no, I do not receive an error and plots instead, but all plots share the same bins, from 1,000,000 to 3,000,000 :/

Comment: @ChrisFoobar I don't have your data so it is extremely difficult to help you more. The problem could be that since your bin values are so high, you do not see the smaller values in the histogram like 1, 2, 3, 5, 300, 600.. etc. You might need a logarithmic x-scale using `ax.set_xscale('log')`